Did Hanuman write a Bhashya on Bhagavad Gita?
I was looking through OPenn's Indic Collection of medieval Hindu manuscripts can be found here, Collection Indica and I found a manuscript called Śrīmadbhagavadgītābhāṣyasya hanumadracitasya prāraṃbho'yaṃ. The link of which is here, Śrīmadbhagavadgītābhāṣyasya hanumadracitasya prāraṃbho'yaṃ. So, is it true that Hanuman wrote a whole commentary on Bhagavad Gita. Is it a scholar known as Hanuman?
